# aws dynamoDB iOS sample code

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Does any one manage to run the following sample found in git hub?

[aws-sdk-ios-samples / DynamoDBSample /](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/DynamoDBSample)

It runs but id doesn't actually create any table when I go back to my aws DynamoDb Console and check.

I believe this sample is unnecessarily  complicated. can some one post a simple insert operation to add a one row record to an existing table from objective-C?

I tried [one ducmentation](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1U4RV2QI1MVWS/Amazon-DynamoDB-on-Mobile-Part-1-Loading-Data) also and it have a compiler error for `DynamoDBGetItemRequest` I am using `awsiossdk v2`

Comment: Why would one want to directly access a database from a distributed client application like that without an intervening web service anyway? Doing so would be a huge security risk.

Comment: That is the recommendation I get from one of aws documentations. And it made sense to me too. Since they have their own security feature in place. It wouldn't be cost effective to run a server instance and also a DB. I will eventually use a server instance for certain business logic that is unique to the application. But other than that if it is a simple read and write it is better to access it directly.

Comment: Yes but to do it this way you would need to either create a specific IAM profile for each application user and inject their IAM credentials dynamically at runtime, or you would need to expose a single set of hard-coded account credentials in your application distribution.  If somebody wants to crack your app they would then have your credentials.

Comment: Right, it depends also how badly one want to crack it, it is good to know pros and cons a head of time. One can make a decision weather security or cost deepening the kind of service they provide.

Though I hope soon, one will answer my question above.

Comment: You may be using different regions on your sample app and AWS Management Console. Currently, the sample uses `AWSRegionUSEast1` by default. On your AWS Management Console, what region are you looking at?

Comment: my DynamoDB console shows it is in US East (N. Virginia). and yes on the sample it shows AWSRegionUSEast1. so all East is under AWSRegionUSEast1?

Comment: I am now getting `Error: [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSDynamoDBErrorDomain Code=1 "null" UserInfo=0x109f38f10 {NSLocalizedDescription=null}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. The issue was on **permission**. I have created an **identityPool** then create a **role** and give this role a permission to the pool. So even though it can authenticate and access the pool but it didn't have a permission to the DynamoDB.